# How can I use Genymotion with Smartface?

Tags: android, genymotion, smartface.io

I am trying to use Genymotion on Smartface, but I could not it yet.

Can we use Genymotion for Smartface?

Is there any way for emulating our project on Genymotion?

I tried what Doruk wrote but Smartface is not still noticing the Genymotion virtual device.

Is there any other solution for this problem?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use GenyMotion with Smartface App Studio.

You can read more about it;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/genymotion

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not work. I got the following error.

Checking Android SDK Configuration.
Searching for Devices...
Could not detect any connected Android device on your computer!

Same issue again? Please refer to Troubleshooting document!

Comment: It does not work. Is there anyone knows the solution for this problem?